# SMSG Materials Available

Tags: reference-books, struggling-students, new-math

Do you know anyone or any institution interested in accepting a donation of a relatively complete set of SMSG Materials?

I post offering to donate a small collection of School Mathematics Study Group materials which my wife inherited from her father, James C. McCaig. Jim's second career was as a 7/8th Grade Math Teacher in the Cupertino Union School District in Northern California. During his tenure he participated as a co-author of a “Special Edition” of the SMSG Secondary School Mathematics curriculum developed “…explicitly for low-acheiving mathematics students at the 7th and 8th grade levels”.  This edition was sponsored by Stanford University and copyrighted in 1970 though not formally published for distribution to schools.

Our collection includes the the complete Special Edition including both Student Text Books and Teacher’s Commentaries for all 18 Chapters of the Special Edition.

In addition to the Special Edition the collection includes all or part of:

1959 - 61   Junior High School Curricula Texts and matching Teacher’s commentaries

1962 - 64         Secondary Curriculum Texts and Teacher’s Commentaries for Algebra, Matrix Algebra, and Geometry

1965            Revision to Secondary Mathematics Curriculum

1970            Revision to Secondary Mathematics Curriculum

1964 - 70         Total of 36 "Supplementary and Enrichment” or “Reprint” Booklets to extend the Secondary Curriculum

1961 - 69   Total of 14 Reports and Studies on development of    Mathematics Curriculums

The complete collection fits in (2) 1.5 cu.ft. book boxes. We can provide more detail in a spreadsheet for interested parties that reply to this post.

If you are interested or know someone who is please reply to this post.

Comment: That is very generous of you and your wife. While mathematics per se consists of timeless truths, pedagogy changes. It is unlikely that 50 year old, pre-technology new math materials would be directly useful to working teachers (other than as a source of examples). On the other hand, someone interested in the evolution of math education would doubtless find it quite interesting. If you don't get any takers here, perhaps you could send some emails to department chairs in universities with a strong graduate-level program in math education.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you suggest any specific Universities? We've offered them to one University of California and one Cal State campus but neither was interested.  Near as I can tell based on online search UC has a full set in their archive.

Comment: I suggest you edit your post so that it includes a question.  Perhaps something like "Do you know anyone who is interested in accepting this donation?"

Comment: I honestly have no idea. In addition to universities, you could perhaps try home schooling associations. Parents who home school are not (yet) bound to common core standards. Some might find it useful. Dating myself, I was raised learning New Math in elementary school. I rather liked it and suspect that it was one of the reasons I eventually went into mathematics. Even though there was a reaction against it, many of the ideas were quite helpful.

Comment: There may be a home for them at the University of Michigan -- I am making inquiries with the appropriate parties and will follow up if I get an affirmative response.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the copyright status of these books. Some Sputnik-era books of this type (e.g., the Berkeley physics series) were funded by the NSF, and there are notices on the copyright page saying that they are therefore free for anyone to use after a certain date (typically ca. 1975). If these materials could be legally digitized, they would be of much more use to the world than sitting on the shelf.

Answer (score 4):

I know a research group in the School of Education at the University of Michigan that would be very happy to receive them.  My email address is in my profile.